# make lint using ICC compiler

Tags: gcc, makefile, lint, icc

Can Intel's icc compiler produce Lint results like gcc does with 'make lint' command ? I checked but could not found anything, is there any other alternative to do so?

Answer (score 1):

A `make lint` command sounds like some particular makefile.  Checking the default rules for GNU make does not show one (though you could have this with a file named `lint.c`).

`gcc` supports several compiler warnings, but does not do what `lint` does: combined analysis across multiple files.  `icc` provides *similar* compiler warnings, and recognizes enough of `gcc`'s warnings to allow it to be used interchangeably in some makefiles.  However, *strict* warnings do differ.  In both cases, those are considered part of *static analysis*.  Some tools go further (`clang`, for instance provides extra compiler warnings with its `--analyze` option, though this too falls short of the multiple-file feature of `lint`).  I use these compilers, have configure script options to check for and turn them on.  But at the moment, the only tool which I am using that provides multiple-file analysis is Coverity.  (Some people find [`splint`](http://splint.org/) useful; I have tried it more than once and not agreed).

Here are a few links which are useful for further reading:

- *[Static Analysis Overview](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-9B795CE3-8341-47C1-83A9-614AB60110B3.htm)*, Intel C++ Compiler XE 13.1 User and Reference Guides (which by the way does not mention `lint`)
- *[Parallel Lint](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/parallel-lint)* by Andrey Karpov, which includes notes on static analysis in the Intel compiler
- *[lint still useful?](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/793289-lint-still-useful)*, newsgroup thread listing possibilities